# Why is "Implement Interface Explicitly" only available sometimes and not also "Implement Interface" (i.e. implicitly)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was just trying to (re)implement my interface on a class where it was already implemented because I added some properties to the interface.  The existing properties were implicitly implemented, i.e. I had chosen this option when I first implemented it:

[image]

Now when I went to re-implement it doing the same thing after I added the new properties to the interface, I only had the option to implement *explicitly*:

[image]

Why does this happen sometimes?  I've done this plenty of times before where it's worked as "expected", and it always just adds the missing member implementations.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad -- I know that.  That really isn't relevant.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: Judging by the question it's probably safe to assume he knows what explicitly implementing interfaces means.

Comment: Dammit, now I can't repro.  I'm trying to work up a code example.  Will post if I find one.  Still, the pictures speak for themselves.

Comment: @BoltClock my  mistake did'nt read the question well

Comment: Check if you don't have private or protected member with the same name as new interface member. Then it cannot be auto-implemented implicitly, because then you will have both public and private member with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If the option where actually there, and it would actually add in the stubs for the methods to implicitly implement the interface, then the code wouldn't compile, as you'd have two methods with the same signature (since you already have the interface's methods as methods of the class).  The only other real sensible behavior for that option, were it to be left in, would be for it to just do nothing (as there is already an implicit implementation).

Comment: Not true, I do this all the time.  It just adds the missing ones.

Comment: @rory.ap You *have* no missing ones.

Comment: I don't get it. OP says he has class with interface implemented, then adds new member to an interface. So this member is missing in the class and OP wants to implement it.

Comment: @Evk The op's code already is fulfilling the interface contract of the updated interface.